# LINQ: Sum values of XML nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML document and I would like to sum all elements of a specific name. How do I do this?

Comment: What is the format of your XML? What have you previously tried? A little more information would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't matter, really, what the specific format is.  The question is answerable without more detail.

Answer (score 7):

You can start with the following code, which sums the value of `specificName` elements anywhere in the document (`Descendants` returns a collection of all elements with the specified name, regardless how deeply nested they are):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("doc.xml");
var sum = (from nd in doc.Descendants("specificName")
           select Int32.Parse(nd.Value)).Sum();
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the query syntax, you could write something like:

```
var sum = doc.Descendants("specificName").Sum(nd => 
            Int32.Parse(nd.Value));
```

The examples assume that the value is stored as a text inside the element and that it is an integer.

Comment: Also, you don't have to parse the element value like that, there is an operator overload that allows you to simply cast the element as its contained type. i.e. select (int)nd;

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is your XML:

```
<nodes>
     <reading c='1'>17</reading>
     <reading c='2'>18</reading>
     <reading c='3'>19</reading>
     <reading c='4'>21</reading>
     <reading c='5'>4</reading>
     <reading c='6'>3</reading>
     <reading c='7'>7</reading>
</nodes>
```

Then use this code to sum the values of the `reading` elements:

```
public void Run()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileToLoad);
    System.Console.WriteLine("\nSumming:");
    var sum = doc.Element("nodes")
                 .Elements("reading")
                 .Sum(n => int.Parse(n.Value));

    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", sum);
}
```